# Failing to match input string

Tags: python

What's wrong with this code!
Does not work in python!
Says error in line 4!
Edit version!

```
print ("Hello to my site")
print ("Enter your username")
kristens = "some value"
username = input()
if input() == kristens:
    print ("Hello Kristens Taurins")
else:
    print ("Access denied")
```

When I enter username `kristens` that it does not print the text as needed.

Comment: You have omitted `:` after your `if` statement.and you need to use `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: Why would you expect `fater` to print the "Hello Kristens Taurins" message? Your password isn't "fater", it's "some value".

Comment: sorrys computer errror

Comment: If you want "kristens" to be your password, you either need to change the third line to `kristens = "kristens"` or change the fifth line to `if input() == "kristens":`

Answer (score 3):

If then statements need comparison clauses and colons.

It should be:

```
# = is not a comparison in Python, == is.
# colon added for if statement
if username == kristens:
    print ("Hello Kristens Taurins")
else:
    print ("Access denied")
```

As also noted, kristens is a variable, so unless it's defined ahead of time, this will not work.

You need to do:

```
kristens = "some value"
```

Comment: kristens = "some value" , where to add it in and do you literally write this

Comment: Before the actual comparison. Please, take an intro course to Python, or do Learn Python the Hard Way. If you do not know basic syntax and variables in Python, life will be hard.

Answer (score 2):

```
print ("Hello to my site") 

print ("Enter your username") 
username = input() 
if username == kristens: # <- == and add a : 
    print ("Hello Kristens Taurins") 
else:
    print ("Access denied")
```

`=` is for assignment, `==` is for comparison. As DSM commented you also need to make sure `kristens` is defined somewhere or you will also get a `NameError`.
You can also pass the string to input:

```
username = input("Enter your username")
```

Comment: Unless `kristens` is a variable, this won't work either.. (I suspect the OP meant to include quotation marks, but for all I know it's a variable with the full name..)

Comment: Another interesting downvote